# Checkbox Condicional

Tags: javascript, angular

Preciso realizar uma validação ao selecionar algumas opções no seguinte checkbox:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

A regra é a seguinte:

Se o IMPEDITIVO estiver selecionado com "S", o EXECUTADO deve estar "N". Porém ambos podem estar como N mas nunca podem ser ambos S.
Ou seja, ao selecionar um, o outro deve ser descelecionado, porém a página (que é uma página de edição) será sempre carregada com uma das opções selecionadas.

O que estou tentando fazer até o momento é isso:

```
  comparaImpeditivoExecutado1(ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO) {
if(ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusImpeditivo){
  ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusExecutado = false;
}
else {
  ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusExecutado = true;
}
```

}

Mas aparentemente não está resolvendo.

Comment: Você precisa passar por parâmetro quem está alterando no momento, assim você verifica o status do outro, por exemplo: `if(this) other = false;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar a tag `input` com o `type="radio"` e `name="radio"`.

```html
<body>
    <input class="checkClass" type="radio" name="radio" id="checkbox1">
    <label for="checkbox1">checkbox 1</label>
    <input class="checkClass" type="radio" name="radio" id="checkbox2">
    <label for="checkbox2">checkbox 2</label>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Transformei os valores em boolean e no component manipulo eles da seguinte maneira:

```
checkboxExecutado(ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO) {
ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusExecutado = !ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusExecutado;
ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusImpeditivo = false;
```

}

checkboxImpeditivo(ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO) {
ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusImpeditivo = !ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusImpeditivo;
ocorrenciaSolicitacaoVO.statusExecutado = false;
}

Me atendeu.